# How to install driver for T2U for Ubuntu 22.04.1?

Tags: networking

I'm installing the Ubuntu 22.04.1 and I realize that the instruction to install T2U driver requires Internet connection. However, I'm installing it for the first time on a running Windows 10 PC. Can I get its driver in Windows 10?

Comment: Please explain how you are running a Ubuntu install on Windows.

Comment: You can connect to the internet while installing Ubuntu. In case T2U is some sort of wireless adapter that needs a driver, use USB tethering from your phone to connect to the internet.

Comment: Can you post the instruction to install the driver?